# Spring @Transactional method and class

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I understand that @Transactional annotation in class affect all the method and @Transactional annotation in method only affect this method and override the class annotation.

But, this code makes sense?(no more methods in class)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Service extends AbstractCrudService<A,Repository> {

  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public Optional<A> getByApplicant(B b) {
     return repository.findByB(b);
  }
```

Is the same if put @Transactional annotation only in method?

```
@Service
public class Service extends AbstractCrudService<A,Repository> {

  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public Optional<A> getByApplicant(B b) {
     return repository.findByB(b);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples work the same way

@Transactional on the class set on all methodos with @Transactional, but if you put @Transactional o method, this replace the class annotation

Answer (score 0):

The @Transactional annotation on the class level will be applied to every method in the class.

However, when a method is annotated with @Transactional (like, getByApplicant(B b)) this will take precedence over the transactional settings defined at the class level.

More about it:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html